# How to remove the arifacts

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, artifacts

I am applying some operations on an image and the result image should resemble the image posted in the first figure below, but my resultant image as you see it in figure 2 contains unwanted structure or artifacts.

how can I eliminate these artifacts?

**figure 1:**

[image]
**figure 2:**

[image]

Comment: It would probably help if you describe these operations.

Comment: and also add the input image ...What about apply some treshold to filter out the gray unsaturated stuff?